# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I obtain this error in my project:

```
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.JDBCBrokerFactory
```

tag error:  
I'm new about this technology and I read and it can be the wrong dynamic web project folder. This is mine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61oxg.png)

The project folder is correct?

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle
>   transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Esercizio]]
>   in state [STARTING_PREP]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1628)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1608)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:764)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2328)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1046)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:721)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1299)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> lug 13, 2018 10:30:10 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder
>   startInternal GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war
>   StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Esercizio]
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed:
>   C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4\webapps\Esercizio:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the
>   named factory class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested
>   exception for details.    at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1050)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:721)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1299)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the
>   named factory class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested
>   exception for details.    at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:876)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:870)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was
>   an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named
>   factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See
>   the nested exception for details.     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getBrokerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
>     ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread
>   without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed
>   app   at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.getContext(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansFinder.getSingletonInstance(WebBeansFinder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.getInstance(WebBeansContext.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.currentInstance(WebBeansContext.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.findBm(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:168)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.toString(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)    at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)    at
>   java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:559)  at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1280)    at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:865)    at
>   java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)  at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:841)    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.getMessage(Localizer.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.toString(Localizer.java:309)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.record(JULOpenJPALog.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.trace(JULOpenJPALog.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationProviderImpl.setInto(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:764)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newInstance(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.invokeFactory(Bootstrap.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:65)
>     ... 21 more
>
> lug 13, 2018 10:30:10 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Esercizio]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Esercizio]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed:
>   C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4\webapps\Esercizio:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the
>   named factory class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested
>   exception for details.    at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1311)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating
>   application failed:
>   C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4\webapps\Esercizio:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the
>   named factory class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested
>   exception for details.    at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1050)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:721)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1299)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the
>   named factory class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested
>   exception for details.    at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:876)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an
>   error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory
>   class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the
>   nested exception for details.     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:870)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was
>   an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named
>   factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See
>   the nested exception for details.     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getBrokerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
>     ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread
>   without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed
>   app   at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.getContext(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansFinder.getSingletonInstance(WebBeansFinder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.getInstance(WebBeansContext.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.currentInstance(WebBeansContext.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.findBm(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:168)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.toString(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)    at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)    at
>   java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:559)  at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1280)    at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:865)    at
>   java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)  at
>   java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:841)    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.getMessage(Localizer.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.toString(Localizer.java:309)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.record(JULOpenJPALog.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.trace(JULOpenJPALog.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationProviderImpl.setInto(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:764)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newInstance(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.invokeFactory(Bootstrap.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:65)
>     ... 21 more
>
> lug 13, 2018 10:30:10 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> lug 13, 2018 10:30:10 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

Comment: Can you show the expanded content of log file.

Comment: update with stack track error!